# Synonym for exposure/exposed (in the context of health/disease)

Tags: synonyms

I've used the word exposure three times in a row, and I need to replace one of them to reduce redundancy, but I can't seem to find a fitting synonym.

Here's the actual sentences:

> What is even more troubling about DDT IRS is the increased human **exposure**. Since DDT is sprayed directly to the inside walls of homes, humans are constantly **exposed**. **Exposure** to DDT has been linked to breast cancer and diabetes, and has been classified as a hormone disruptor and a possible human carcinogen .

I would like to replace the middle "exposed" more than the other two "exposure"'s

*EDIT*
FYI IRS in this context stands for indoor residual spraying. Not internal revenue service

Comment: *Vulnerable* [to it]? *In contact*? *Subject* to contact?

Comment: Hm, I need a more active verb. I want to emphasise that humans are being effected by this chemical (the DDT), because they're living with it, breathing it, etc.

Comment: Apart from being slightly ridiculous in the context of the preceding sentence, your *third* usage is completely unnecessary. Just delete the words *exposure to* there. I don't see anything much wrong with leaving the first two as they are - but if it bothers you, just merge the first two sentences using a comma, and delete *humans are constantly exposed* as well (if it's sprayed on the inside walls of homes, it's blindingly obvious people are exposed/in close proximity, so why bother spelling it out?).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is effectively "writing advice"

Comment: ... And this eliminates the incorrect 'Exposure to X ... has been classified as a hormone disruptor and a possible human carcinogen '.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you, I think I'll splice it, etc.

P.S. sorry that everyone is getting their knickers in a twist about how this question is off topic. This is my first time using ELU, and I assumed that asking about a synonym  was an appropriate question.

Comment: @user87810: I've only offered my opinion on how to get you out of an awkward position in terms of your writing. FWIW I upvoted jwpat7's suggested alternatives, but half of my upvote was for the second paragraph anyway. I don't think it's usually a good idea to search for alternative words to avoid repetition in situations like yours - mostly they only arise because of deeper problems (in this case, the text itself is inherently repetitive, and ringing the changes by using different words for the same thing won't represent an "improvement").

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why not say:

Even more troubling, since DDT IRS is sprayed directly to the inside walls of homes, is the constant human exposure to it. As well as being linked to breast cancer and diabetes, it has been classified as a hormone disruptor and a possible human carcinogen.

You have saved 7 words and only have one 'exposure'.

Answer (score 1):

You might write  “humans frequently encounter it” (or  “repeatedly encounter it”, etc) in place of “humans are constantly exposed”.

Note, your writing sample has more-serious problems than the one you ask about, but ELU is not a writing-advice service.

Comment: Thank you, but your suggestion was not very good, and my writing sample has absolutely no "serious" problems. You shouldn't judge a writing sample that is only an excerpt from a much longer entry.

Comment: @user87810: The sentence 'Exposure to DDT has been linked to breast cancer and diabetes, and has been classified as a hormone disruptor and a possible human carcinogen' contains a schoolboy howler. People are exercised here about the need to address more than a single point. The request for a synonym for variants of 'expose', together with a correct if stylistically challenged example, would be by no means off-topic.